# Trainable Classifiers in NLTK and Sklearn for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I have followed a tutorial to make a basic trainable sentiment analysis program using mostly nltk and some sklearn, however, I am only using 5 classifiers (and then using a voting system): LogisticRegression, BernoulliNB, MultinomialNB, LinearSVC, and NuSVC. I would like to expand upon this program, however, I don't know where to go. **If I tune these 5 classifiers, can that create a good sentiment analysis program? If not, what other trainable classifiers are there (I've tried training MaxEnt but I don't think that it will give me the results I am looking for and it takes forever to train)?**

Comment: Instead of using classifiers of the same type(2 naive bayes and 2 SVCs) try introducing some different types of classifiers such as Decision Trees or Random Forests.

Comment: What is a "good" sentiment analysis program? I.e. what performance are you after? And do you really need to throw so many different classifiers at the problem? I would think getting one or more to work well, through careful feature selection (start by adding more features) and tuning, would be a better use of your time.